# Removing certain items in a pandas.core.series

Tags: python, pandas, series

Given a pandas.core.series, is it possible to remove certain items from each index in and retain the ones that i want to keep? For example:

```
country=['China','USA','Asia','Brazil']
contents={'Tags': ['China;Panda;Brazil;Plug','USA;China;Asia','Brazil;Peanut']}
df=pd.DataFrame(contents)
tags=df["Tags"]
```

I wish to discard the values that are not in the country list and keep the rest of the values. So, for tags[0] the result should be [China,Brazil]. tags[1] all the values remain and tags[2] the result should be [Brazil]

```
tags = tags.str.split(';')
```

I have attempted to split the ; inbetween each value but i am uncertain of how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[val for val in a_list if val in country] for a_list in df.Tags.str.split(";")]
```

For each list after splitting, keep only the values that are in `country` list

to get

```
[['China', 'Brazil'], ['USA', 'China', 'Asia'], ['Brazil']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Exploding and regrouping is also an option:

```py
import pandas as pd

country = ['China', 'USA', 'Asia', 'Brazil']
contents = {'Tags': ['China;Panda;Brazil;Plug',
                     'USA;China;Asia',
                     'Brazil;Peanut']}
df = pd.DataFrame(contents)

e = df.Tags.str.split(';').explode()
tags = e[e.isin(country)].groupby(level=0).agg(list).tolist()
print(tags)
```

`tags`:

```
[['China', 'Brazil'], ['USA', 'China', 'Asia'], ['Brazil']]
```

---

An option with `merge` rather than `isin`:

```py
import pandas as pd

country = ['China', 'USA', 'Asia', 'Brazil']
contents = {'Tags': ['China;Panda;Brazil;Plug',
                     'USA;China;Asia',
                     'Brazil;Peanut']}
df = pd.DataFrame(contents)

e = df.Tags.str.split(';').explode().reset_index()

tags = e.merge(
    pd.DataFrame(country, columns=['Tags']),
    on='Tags'
).groupby('index')['Tags'].agg(list).tolist()
print(tags)
```

`tags`:

```
[['China', 'Brazil'], ['China', 'USA', 'Asia'], ['Brazil']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to do the parsing and copy the information to a new column. So, for example, something like:

```
from functools import partial
import numpy as np


def pars_func(countries,content_str):
    ret_str=''
    for tag in content_str.split(';'):
           if tag in country:
                ret_str=ret_str+';'+tag
    if ret_str== '':
        return np.nan
    else:
        return ret_str[1:].split(';')


df['Tags']=df['Tags'].apply(partial(pars_func,country))
```